# how to use angular js datatable with export buttons

Tags: angularjs

```
dataTables.buttons.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined
at dataTables.buttons.min.js:5
at dataTables.buttons.min.js:5
at dataTables.buttons.min.js:5
```

I am getting this type of error if i try to place button extensions CDN in angular Js please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your datatables dependecies

```
<!-- Datatables -->
<link href="path to/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="path to/datatables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Datatables Buttons -->
<script src="path to/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Datatables -->
<script src="path to/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="path to/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

Include angular datatables in your module

```
angular
    .module('app', [            
        'datatables',
        'datatables.buttons'
    ])
```

Inject DTOptionsBuilder and define the options in your controller

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, DTOptionsBuilder) {
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withButtons([
                'copy',
                'pdf',
                'excel'
            ])
            .withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lTtipr');
    });
```

Declare datatables and dt-options directive on your table

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table>
```

Angular Datatables docs: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withButtons